# Solr related data search with dates stored as String

Tags: solr

I have the dates stored in Solr as String.
E.g., "HIRE_DATE":["2012-10-01"], for different years.
Can someone help to find the right way to search the HIRE_DATE for first quarter of 2012 or for a particular month.

Unable to search the data with HIRE_DATE:"2012-10".

Answer (score 0):

If it's stored in a `string` field type as you've written and you have indexed the content with proper datestamps (i.e. `2020-09-01`, not `2020-9-1`), you can do:

```
# only september, 2020
HIRE_DATE:[2020-09 TO 2020-10}
# or
HIRE_DATE:2020-09*
```

For a quarter you can modify the first one:

```
# q4/2020
HIRE_DATE:[2020-10 TO 2021-01}

# You can also use inclusive and full datestamps:
HIRE_DATE:[2020-10-01 TO 2020-12-31]
```

This works since the lexical sort order for these datestamps as text will match properly to the lower/upper bounds expressed by the strings. If the indexed format was without proper formatting (like `2020-9-1`) this wouldn't work, since `2020-9` sorts after `2020-10`. But `2020-09` sorts before `2020-10`, so this strategy then works as expected.

Comment: I have a data in below format.                                                                          
                                                                                                                          
      "HIRE_DATE":["2000-09-18"]},
      {
        "HIRE_DATE":["2000-09-18"]},
      {
        "HIRE_DATE":["2000-09-11"]},................When searching with  HIRE_DATE:[2000-08 TO 2000-09] it does not show any records.

Comment: Neither of those would match your query - You'll need to use `TO 2000-10`, since `2000-09` would sort before either of your examples. Also - make sure that your field type actually is `string` (and not `text` or something similar).